# Solving an integral vectorial equation by iterations

Tags: integral-equations, vector-calculus, iteration

I'm triying to solve a problem like the following:
$$
\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}=\binom{f_0(t)}{g_0(t)}+\lambda\int_0^t ds\hat{A}(s)\binom{f(s)}{g(s)},
$$
where $f_0(t),g_0(t)$ and $\hat{A}(t)$ (a $2\times2$ matrix) are known. Here, $\lambda$ is a scale factor.

So, by iteration, it is easy to find that up to order $\lambda^2$:
$$
\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}=\binom{f_0(t)}{g_0(t)}+\lambda\int_0^t ds\hat{A}(s)\left[\binom{f_0(s)}{g_0(s)}+\lambda\int_0^s ds'\hat{A}(s')\binom{f(s')}{g(s')}\right]
$$
Then:
$$
\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}=\binom{f_0(t)}{g_0(t)}+\lambda\int_0^t ds\hat{A}(s)\binom{f_0(s)}{g_0(s)}+\lambda^2\int_0^t ds\hat{A}(s)\int_0^s ds'\hat{A}(s')\binom{f(s')}{g(s')}
$$

I wish to perform the latter at some desired order $O(\lambda^n)$, and I suspect that it would be done with the command `Nest`

For example, let me define
$$
\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}=\binom{\cos t}{\sin t},
$$
and
$$
\hat{A}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
t & 0 \\
0 & -t \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I wrote the following code:

```
T[f_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]} + 
   l*Integrate[{{t, 0}, {0, -t}} f /. t -> s, {s, 0, t}];
Nest[T, t, 1] // MatrixForm
```

(here `l` means $\lambda$  ).

The results is:

```
{{(t^3 \[Lambda])/3 + Cos[t], 
  Cos[t]}, {Sin[t], -((t^3 \[Lambda])/3) + Sin[t]}}
```

or
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda t^3/3+\cos t & \cos t \\
\sin t & -\lambda t^3/3+\sin t \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which differs of the analytical result
$$
\binom{\cos t +\lambda\left(\cos t +t\sin t-1\right)}{\sin t+\lambda\left(t\cos t-\sin t\right)}
$$

Note that the Mathematica result is a matrix, not a vector.

I've tried with dot products inside the integral but it doesn't work.

Do you have any clue to attack this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: “I've tried with dot products inside the integral but it doesn't work.” How did you try?

Answer (score 5):

```
f[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}

OverHat[A][t_] := {{t, 0}, {0, -t}}

T[k_] := f[t] + λ*Integrate[k . OverHat[A][s], 
     {s, 0, t}]

T[f[s]]
```

> {Cos[t] + λ (-1 + Cos[t] + t Sin[t]), λ (t Cos[t] -
> Sin[t]) + Sin[t]}

```
Nest[T, f[s], 2]
```

> {Cos[t] +    1/2 t^2 λ (Cos[t] + λ (-1 + Cos[t] + t
> Sin[t])),   1/2 t^2 λ (-λ (t Cos[t] - Sin[t]) -
> Sin[t]) + Sin[t]}

Comment: Thanks @Syed.  But the code that you developed doesn't rename the upper limit of the nested integral. So then, it has several integrations over [0,t], and if one wish to go the third iteration it is necessary to change the integration limit.

Comment: I think that it is solved by the following modification:  `T[k_] := f[t] + \[Lambda]*Integrate[k.A[t] /. t -> s, {s, 0, t}]`

Comment: You could write an improved answer and say where the difference occurs by nesting further. I don't have insight into these recursive equations due to a lack of any previous experience.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the correct recursion for the upper limit of each integral, the code posted by @Syed needs just a little modification, namely:

```
A[t_] := {{t, 0}, {0, -t}}

T[k_] := f[t] + \[Lambda]*Integrate[k.A[t] /. t -> s, {s, 0, t}]
```

Otherwise, all the nested integrals would have the same integration limit.