# Two variable recursive integral equation

Tags: integral-equations, iteration

I'm trying to improve the question posted in [Solving an integral vectorial equation by iterations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268888/solving-an-integral-vectorial-equation-by-iterations/268889?noredirect=1#comment670840_268889) but when the iterations are for two variables. I mean, suposse that I have the following integral equation:
$$
f(t)=g(t)+\int_0^t ds A(s,t)f(s)
$$
so that in the second iteration it should be
$$
h(t)=g(t)+\int_0^t ds A(s,t)\left[g(s)+\int_0^s ds'A(s',s)g(s')\right]
$$

Now, I've tried with:

```
T[k_] := g[t] + Integrate[A[s, t].k /. t -> s, {s, 0, t}]
Nest[T, g[s], 2]
```

But the result is:
$$
h(t)=g(t)+\int_0^t ds A(s,t)\left[g(s)+\int_0^s ds'A(s',s')g(s')\right]
$$
i.e., in the second integral the function $$A(s',s')$$ the argument is not well evaluated.

Do you know a how to follow in order to rename the second variable in $A(s,t)$ for each step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is that in this sort of recursion (where you wrap each result in a new integral), you need to know what the variable you'll be integrating over is. So the input and output for `T` can be lists, where the first element is the expression and the second is the symbol. We'll generate a fresh new free variable each iteration via `Unique`. (This will append numbers to the variable name to make sure the variable is fresh.)

```
T[{k_, s_Symbol}] :=
  With[{t = Unique["t"]}, (* t is a fresh symbol *)
       {g[t] + Integrate[A[s, t].k, {s, 0, t}], t}
      ]

(* Take the first element of the result to get just the expression. *)
(* Note that the initial expression now needs to be a pair too! *)

First @ Nest[T, {g[s], s}, 2]
```

It might be nicer to rewrite this using functions instead of pairs. Here's one that's cleaner to use (at the expense of a more complicated definition), which takes in a function instead of a pair:

```
ClearAll[T]
T[f_] := 
 With[{s = Unique["s"]}, 
  With[{fs = f[s]},
   g[#] + Integrate[A[s, #] . fs, {s, 0, #}] &
 ]]

Nest[T, g, 2]
```

Likewise, this returns a function that can be applied to things.

You might find it nicer to use `Inactive[Integrate][...]` in the definition of `T`, and then `Activate` it later. This avoids the process of Mathematica trying to evaluate `Integrate` each time, which makes it slower.